Proving maximality of irreducible components in the Zariski topology.
I am trying to find the decomposition of algebraic sets into irreducible components, and in the cases I am interested in, it is quite easy to find irreducible closed sets whose union is the whole algebraic set. However, an irreducible component must be the maximal subset with this property, and I struggle proving it. Let us maybe work with an example and I am sure I can understand the rest myself:
Why is $V((x,y))\subset V((x,y)) \cup V((y,z))$ a maximal irreducible and closed subset of $ V((x,y)) \cup V((y,z))$? I tried to find contradictions by assuming that a bigger such set, $V(I)$ properly containing $V((x,y))$ existed, but that just lead to the conclusion that it is equivalent to $(x,y)$ having no non-trivial prime subideals which contain $(x,y) \cap (y,z)$, which I do not know how to prove either. Alternatively, I used that $V(I)$ can be decomposed as $V((x,y)) \cup U$ with $U \subset W \setminus V((x,y))$. $U$ is open in $W$, but I do not know how to prove (if it is indeed possible) that $U$ necessarily has non-vanishing interior in $V((y,z))$, which would contradict that $V(I)$ is not the whole set.

In general, if $X=A_1\cup A_2\cup...\cup A_n$ where $A_i$ are closed irreducible subsets and we have $A_i\not\subset A_j$ for any $i\ne j$ then the $A_i$ must be the irreducible components of $X$.
Indeed, let us show that $A_1$ is a component. Assume $A_1\subseteq Y\subseteq X$ is irreducible. $Y$ is contained in $X=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i$, and by irreducibility, must be contained in some $A_i$. Then we get $A_1\subseteq Y\subseteq A_i$. But by assumption, $A_1$ is not contained in any $A_i$ except itself, and thus $i=1$, which means $Y=A_1$.
So in your example $V(x,y)\cup V(y,z)$, you already have the decomposition into irreducible components. Just verify that the two sets are not contained in each other. (this is very easy)

Thank you for your quick reply! However, I still do not understand why irreducibility implies that $Y$ is contained in one $A_i$. Let me clarify my confusion: Irreducibility implies that $Y$ cannot be decomposed into closed subsets, but that still means that $Y$ can be of the form $A_1 \sqcup U$ for $U$ open in $Y$. Why does that lead to contradictions?

@anonymous250 Irreducibility means that if $Y=A\cup B$ is a union of two closed sets then we must have $Y=A$ or $Y=B$. By induction we can easily generalize this from two closed sets to any finite union of closed sets. In my answer, the decomposition into closed sets is $Y=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n (A_i\cap Y)$. So $Y$ must equal one of the sets in the union.

Sorry, of course! Thank you!
